# Adding apache to a user group file upload permission

Tags: php, apache

I have a php script uploading files to a certain folder, currently they are uploading as a 'psacln' group, so that I can delete the files via FTP. This was all working fine when PHP was running as FastCGI, I had to change PHP to run as Apache Module in order to get a php extension to work. But now I can't delete files via PHP script because permission is denied. I assume because now the group 'Apache' is trying to delete the file that belongs to 'psacln'. How do I allow apache to delete those files?

EDIT: ls -alF

```
drwxr-xr-x   2 fugitiveink psacln 4096 Nov 13 14:05 92/
drwxr-xr-x   2 fugitiveink psacln 4096 Nov 13 06:57 93/
drwxr-xr-x   2 fugitiveink psacln 4096 Nov 13 14:12 95/
drwxr-xr-x   2 fugitiveink psacln 4096 Dec 21 18:56 96/
drwxr-xr-x   2 fugitiveink psacln 4096 Dec 21 08:30 97/
drwxr-xr-x   2 fugitiveink psacln 4096 Nov 13 14:26 98/
drwxr-xr-x   2 fugitiveink psacln 4096 Nov 13 14:28 99/
```

Comment: at least you have to grant rights to "Apache" group with root / sudo

Comment: You have to have parent folder to have apache user group and it must be executable.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I assume that you have shell and root access to this system. If so, you can try adding the apache user (typically `apache` or `www-data`) to the `/etc/group` file.

The proper way to do this is to use `usermod`, though I typically just edit the file directly.

In short if your apache user is `apache`, try:

```
sudo usermod apache --append --groups psacln
```

This basically gives the apache user access to any files & directories that are owned by the psacln group.

If this doesn't work, post an example of your directory with the file permissions (`ls -alF`) and we can work from that.

EDIT:

To directly edit the groups file using nano (substitute with whichever editor you're comfortable with):

```
sudo nano /etc/groups
```

and find the `psacln` group and add the `apache` user:

```
psacln:x:130:apache
```

Note that the gid (`130`) will undoubtedly be different.

Comment: didn't work, php is running as `apache:apache` getting `usermod: user psacln does not exist`

Comment: What do you get when you run `sudo groups psacln`? Also can you include the `.` directory in your directory listing edit.

Comment: 'id: psacln: No such user'

Comment: What flavor of linux are you using?

Comment: Linux 2.6.18-028stab092.1 / psa v10.3.1_build1013110726.09 os_CentOS 5

Comment: Redhat? Ubuntu? Something else? I'm a little stumped as the directory listing you provided clearly has the `psacln` group. You could try directly editing the `/etc/group` file.

Comment: yeah I know, cause if i id psacln, it says doesn't exist, I think its redhat, let me confirm

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22018/discussion-between-hafichuk-and-keeg)

Comment: adding apache to psacln group and having the uploaded folders as apache:apache works perfectly via php script and ftp thank you hafichuk

Answer (score -4):

Set the permissions on the upload directory to 777 (wrx for all users). Can you still upload new files? If you can, you should be able to delete files.

Comment: You need to have recursive permission set up. Parent folder also should have permission.

Comment: If you do not share the server with other users, then 777 would be safe permissions. Since you have child directories, they will have to have 777 permission too. `chmod -R a+w .` from the directory shown. You can always change it back if it does not work. If you add apache to the psacln group you will need to set group write permission, `chmod -R g+w .`