# error uploading file using php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem with my upload file function. I'm following [this](http://www.sanwebe.com/2012/06/ajax-file-upload-with-php-and-jquery) website to create the upload form to upload a text file and i just modify it a little. Here's the code:

upload_form.php :

```
//the jquery script is still the same with the website
.....
echo "
    <form action='processupload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data' id=MyUploadForm>
    <input name='FileInput' id='FileInput' type='file' />
    <input type='submit'  id='submit-btn' value='Upload' />
    <img src='images/ajax-loader.gif' id='loading-img' style='display:none;' alt='Please Wait'/>
    </form>
    <div id='progressbox' ><div id='progressbar'></div ><div id='statustxt'>0%</div></div>
    <div id='output'></div>
  ";
```

processupload.php :

```
<?php

if(isset($_FILES["FileInput"]) && $_FILES["FileInput"]["error"]== UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
{
############ Edit settings ##############
//$UploadDirectory  = '/impfile'; //specify upload directory ends with / (slash)
##########################################


//check if this is an ajax request
if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'])){
    die();
}


//Is file size is less than allowed size.
if ($_FILES["FileInput"]["size"] > 5242880) {
    die("File size is too big!");
}

//allowed file type Server side check
switch(strtolower($_FILES['FileInput']['type']))
    {
        case 'text/plain':
            break;
        default:
            die('Unsupported File!'); //output error
}

$File_Name          = $_FILES['FileInput']['name'];

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['FileInput']['tmp_name'], "/impfile/".$File_Name ))
{
    die('Success! File Uploaded.');
}else{
    die('error uploading File!');
}

}
else
{
die('Something wrong with upload! Is "upload_max_filesize" set correctly?');
}
```

The problem is the feedback always showing error

> die('error uploading File!');

I think the problem isn't from the code, because I can't found the php.ini in the same path that phpinfo showed me. I already set the folder (impfile) to be writeable too.

Can someone show me where did I do wrong in the code? Or maybe the php.ini? If the php.ini is the problem, how can I add the php.ini? Or maybe there's something else?

Every help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What permissions did you give the folder?

Comment: @npfedwards BTW, the path has to be a realpath, as the path is.. he's maybe trying to move the file on the realpath /impfile/ and not a relative one, i suppose that he doesn't want this..

Comment: @npfedwards I'm using filezilla and I give 777 as the value. is it wrong?

Comment: @GotchaRob there is a folder name "impfile" in the same folder with processupload.php

Comment: did you try to follow more websites' advice on how to upload files before asking here? I've found many sites have false/outdated/server specific information and a mix and match of many gives the best result, especially understanding the underlying technology

Comment: @YosuaKurniadi "/impfile/" is not a realpath try `getcwd()."/impfile/".$File_Name`instead of `"/impfile/".$File_Name`

Comment: @YosuaKurniadi I try not to use 777 and use 774 with the webserver user in the group just to limit any possible vulnerabilities in giving every user that access. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116708/adding-apache-to-a-user-group-file-upload-permission looks like it might have some help on adding apache to a group if you don't know how.

Comment: thx guys the problem is answered just because the impfile is not a nonroot directory. Thx a lot for the answer guys.

Comment: @npfedwards but if I use 774, I cannot upload it again. Is there any way to use it and still can upload?

Comment: @npfedwards oh and I'm using a webhosting so is there a way to edit the apache?

Comment: @YosuaKurniadi your three numbers in that octal correspond to user (the owner of the file), group (a group of users that can be given specific permissions on the file) and others (everyone else on the system). You need to add apache to a group or change the group to include apache (depending on server the apache user could be called apache, httpd or _www). This all assumes you can ssh into your server.
If you can. `chgrp -R apache impfile` should help (from the folder it's in)

Comment: @npfedwards too bad it didn't support ssh. Thank you npedwards for helping me even until now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try write `impfile/` without first slash. This could be help if the script or directory place in nonroot directory of domain.

Try use `is_uploaded_file($_FILES['FileInput']['tmp_name'])` or/and `$_FILES['FileInput']['size']>0` conditions for additional check.

Comment: how stupid i am! Of course it's not a nonroot directory. Thx a lot CnapoB